# Inserted row before repeater-item prevents RadioButton.Checked postback for this repeater-item only?

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, postback, repeater

I have a repeater filling table-rows with 1 text and multiple `HtmlRadioButtons`, that a user is supposed to check.
Because the list can become quite large, only checking the first N rows is obligatory.
To show this to the user, I add an extra `TableRow` with one `TableCell` (colspan=4) with some instructional text before the first optional row.
I add this row on the repeaters `ItemDataBound`.

On postback all checked radio-buttons before and after the extra row *do* return with their checked values, *except* the one item before which I inserted the extra row.
I tried varying the types for the extra row (`Html/RadioButton`, `Html/TableRow` and `Html/TableCell`), and I tried varying `EnableViewState` on the extra row.
However I can not get this row/radio-button to postback the checked-value, it is always false.

Does anybody know why this value does not postback?
Does anybody know how to add an extra row without preventing the radio-button to postback?

Extra remarks:

- I do not want to add an `OnClick` to the radio-button, as I like to process and store all the values at once
- I dowload the original data in the `Page_Load`, but that does not seem a problem for the other rows/RadioButtons

This is the simplified, condensed code.
The ASPX:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TableRow runat="server">
        <asp:TableCell ID="CategoryName" CssClass="td_1" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'/>
        <asp:TableCell CssClass="td_radio" runat="server">
            <asp:HtmlInputRadioButton type="radio" runat="server"
              ID="rdBelonging"
              Name='<%# Eval("Id") %>'
              value='<%# (int)Enum_BelongsToCategory.Belonging %>'
              data-value='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("ShouldJudge")) ? "mandatory" : "optional" %>'/>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell CssClass="td_radio" runat="server">
            <asp:HtmlInputRadioButton type="radio" runat="server"
              ID="rdNotBelonging"
              Name='<%# Eval("Id") %>'
              value='<%# (int)Enum_BelongsToCategory.NotBelonging %>'
              data-value='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("ShouldJudge")) ? "mandatory" : "optional" %>'/>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <%-- more Enum_BelongsToCategory-ReadioButtons... --%>
    </asp:TableRow>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The code behind to add the line (inspired by this Experts-Exchange-post [Repeater Control -- Adding another table row](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/ASP.NET/Q_23570015.html):

```
protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
        // first get item and show previous checks (if any)
        // ...
        if ( (lDataItem.ShouldJudge == false) && (_prevShouldJudge) ) {
            var lCell = new TableCell { ColSpan = 4, InnerText = "(minimum to check)" };
            var lRow = new TableRow();
            lRow.Cells.Add(lCell);
            e.Item.Controls.AddAt(0, lRow);
        }
        _prevShouldJudge = lDataItem.ShouldJudge;
    }
}
```

The code behind to find the checked RadioButton (inspired by this Chief of the System Blog [find checked radio-button in aspnet](http://remy.supertext.ch/2008/02/find-checked-radio-button-in-aspnet/))

```
private void SaveCategoryJudgements(Product product)
{
    int lRepeaterItemCount = 0;
    foreach (RepeaterItem lItem in repeaterCategories.Items) {
        lRepeaterItemCount ++;
        var lCheckedRadioButton = GetCheckedRadioButton(lItem.Controls);
        if (lCheckedRadioButton != null) {
            int lCategoryId;
            int lJudgement;
            if ( (int.TryParse(lCheckedRadioButton.Attributes["value"], out lJudgement)) 
              && (int.TryParse(lCheckedRadioButton.Name, out lCategoryId)) )
            {
                ClassificationData.SaveDocumentCategoryByUser(product, lCategoryId, (Enum_BelongsToCategory)lJudgement);
            }
        }
    }
}

public HtmlInputRadioButton GetCheckedRadioButton(ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach (Control lControl in controls) {
        if (lControl is HtmlInputRadioButton) {
            var lRadioButton = (HtmlInputRadioButton)lControl;
            if (lRadioButton.Checked == true) 
            {
                return lRadioButton;
            }
        }
        else {
            var lRadioButton = GetCheckedRadioButton(lControl.Controls);
            if (lRadioButton != null) {
                return lRadioButton;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your general approach is correct, IMO it seems you are over complicating the entire thing.

1. You don't need server-side table controls, ie: `<asp:TableRow runat="server">`. By using a server control rather than an html control you are *greatly* over inflating your ViewState. Remember, in order to restore the repeater on PostBack, .NET needs to maintain all server controls in a hidden field that is stored in the page you are serving back to the client. Simple html markup, ie: `<td>`, would suffice here.
2. Rather than adding a new row in code-behind you can simply have a Panel control with visibility set to false. As you bind the repeater, you can set the Panel's visibility to true for the row that requires it.

If you need any code for the above, just ask, I would be happy to provide some.

Also, it is not clear from your question, but do you only have *one* text value to display (CategoryName)? If so, you can remove this part from the repeater and only iterate on the radio buttons.

Why are you using radio buttons. Again, it is not clear from your question, but you state: *all checked radio-buttons before and after the extra row*. This seems to imply that the user can select more than one radio button. The correct usage for radio buttons is if you want the user to only select *one* item. It seems to me a list of checkboxes would be the correct control to use here.

As far as the problem you are having, it is most likely because you are not restoring the dynamically added tablerow on postback and that is messing up the restoration of the ViewState. Remember, in order for the ViewState to be restored correctly, the ***exact number*** of controls must be present when ViewState is restored. If you follow my example of using an update panel, this should alleviate the problem.

**EDIT**

To understand why adding an invisible server control works and adding a new control in the code doesn't, you need to understand how Viewstate works. A thorough explanation can be found here [Understanding ASP.NET View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic4). But in short, because, as I stated earlier: the ***exact number*** of controls must be present when ViewState is restored, when you have server controls that have their visibility set to false, they ***do*** exist when the page is posted back and the ViewState is restored. When you add them via code, you must expolicitly re-add them. I hope that explanation makes sense.

Code example:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>'<%# Eval("Name") %>'</td>
        <td><asp:RadioButton ID="rdBelonging" ...</td>
        <!-- more Enum_BelongsToCategory-RadioButtons... -->
    </tr>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlExplanationRow" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <tr>
        <td colspan=?>....</td>
    </tr>
    </asp:Panel>
</ItemTemplate>
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have multiple rows, each has one text and multiple radio-buttons. Per row only one radio-button can be checked.
But I process all rows at once, after a "Next"-button-click.

Your second point helped me out. I now added a server-side table-row (not a panel) with `visible=false` before the radio-button-row and set it visible for the first optional item. I guess dynamically added controls messes up the postback somehow, but I am not sure how  (in)visible rows would work better.

So I will mark this as answer, but maybe first wait some more on input concerning the why.

Comment: Concerning your first point: I started out with only html-controls, but then 'I' could not find my checked control on postback.
When I added `runat="server"` to my `<input>`, I got an error message about 'the control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate'.
When I changed only the input `<input>` to an asp-control `<asp:HtmlInputRadioButton>`, I got the same error.
So I also changed the row and the cells, and it worked.

But maybe you mean a different approach, and then an code-example might help!

Comment: a) I guess adding an extra row in the `Page_Load` messes up ViewState-comparison only for this RepeaterItem. It might work in `Page_Init`, but for other reasons I use `Page_Load`. An invisible Control in the Repeater prevents an extra element, so it leaves the ViewState intact.

b) I reduced most to html-controls (again), and now I get no more errors on the ViewState, typical...

c) Besides that, I now also removed the _ItemDataBound, by handling the row-visibility and checked-ness in the asp-code (inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600633/injecting-table-row-inside-repeater-item)